# I have an issue with "Hashcat" error "Bitlocker" hash

Tags: encryption, computer-forensics, bitlocker, hashcat

I have a hash file from the image, my device is Surface Pro BitLocker encrypted image

Recovery Key hash #0:
$bitlocker$2$16$57debb77a3b130a92397f8c063049274$1048576$12$20cfa3155178d70198020000$60$ad91090585684fe3da68e053c0cbfdaae24e8bd5c6b50978790b964d3b2a808c3394a833c690cc9c99c0364d9df1fac40bdcadcd2b987a7d780bfdc3

when I run

hashcat.exe -m 22100 bitlocker.txt rockyou.txt

I get an error

Hashfile 'bitlocker.txt' on line 1 ($bitlo...9df1fac40bdcadcd2b987a7d780bfdc3): Salt-value exception
No hashes loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Note also that Hashcat only supports $bitlocker$1$...

You should try to extract a $1 hash ... alternatively it should work with [bitcracker](https://github.com/e-ago/bitcracker)

Comment: Not exactly. It can also crack $0 hashes